# pdfbox font cache error

Tags: fonts, pdfbox

In */home/user1/.fonts* folder there was one xyz.otf file. This font is used by my program that uses pdfbox to generate postscript from pdf file. Later I removed the xyz.otf file and ran '**fc-cache -fv**' and '**fc-list**'. As expected, xyz is gone.

However, when I run the java program I get error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/user1/.fonts/xyz.otf (No such file or directory)
```

It seems the old font is cached some where (by whom?). But I checked /tmp and ~user1/.cache and cannot find anything related. How can I clear the cache? I use CentOS 7 and pdfbox 2.0.8. Thanks!

Comment: Could be the font cache. See your home dir, the file ".pdfbox.cache". You can delete it. Could be that it detects only if there are new fonts and not if fonts have been deleted.

Comment: It is .pdfbox.cache. Can you make your comment an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the file ".pdfbox.cache" in your user home directory. That one stores the locations of all the fonts on your system. I suspect that it detects only if there are new fonts and not if fonts have been deleted.

Update: This will be fixed in version 2.0.9 (issue [PDFBOX-4129](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4129)).